# Why can't I initialize this EF class?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF Core and I'm trying to instantiate an object to persist it back to the DB.

If I try to use this syntax I get the below error:

```
            var u = new BusinessEntities.Models.EF.User(){
            u.FirstName = user.FirstName,
            u.LastName = user.LastName,
            u.Email = user.Email,
            u.EmployeeNo = user.EmployeeNumber,
            u.IsActive = user.IsActive,
            u.LastUpdatedDte = DateTime.Now,
            u.RegisteredDte = DateTime.Now
            };
            db.User.Add(u);

Cannot initialize type with a collection initializer because it does not implement System.Collections.IEnumerable
```

But this works fine:

```
                var u = new BusinessEntities.Models.EF.User();
                u.FirstName = user.FirstName;
                u.LastName = user.LastName;
                u.Email = user.Email;
                u.EmployeeNo = user.EmployeeNumber;
                u.IsActive = user.IsActive;
                u.LastUpdatedDte = DateTime.Now;
                u.RegisteredDte = DateTime.Now;
                db.User.Add(u);
```

Why is one ok and not the other?

Comment: Remove the `u.` on the properties in your first example.

Answer (score 2):

Because the first example is not valid syntax. You want something more like:

```
var u = new BusinessEntities.Models.EF.User
{
    FirstName = user.FirstName,
    LastName = user.LastName,
    Email = user.Email,
    EmployeeNo = user.EmployeeNumber,
    IsActive = user.IsActive,
    LastUpdatedDte = DateTime.Now,
    RegisteredDte = DateTime.Now
};
db.User.Add(u);
```